# Como compartilhar audio do app para o Whatsapp?

Tags: android, áudio

Meu código  consegue abrir Whatsapp mas quando seleciona a pessoa nao envia nada e volta para o Whatsapp, como posso compartilhar o áudio  do meu app ?

> código  que estou usando

```
public void onClickshe (View v) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String audioClipFileName="starboy.mp3";
    shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Compartilhando no 
     whatsapp"));
   }
```

Comment: Onde está este audio?

Comment: Esta em res > raw > starboy.mp3

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
/**
 * É necessário salvar o  arquivo no External Storage do usuário, para compartilhar
 */
public void onClickshe() {
    InputStream inputStream;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        // Carregamos o arquivo...
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.starboy);
        /** Retorna o diretório primário de armazenamento compartilhado/externo. Este diretório pode
              * atualmente não está acessível se ele foi montado pelo usuário em seus
          * computador, foi removido do dispositivo, ou algum outro problema tem aconteceu.**/
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sound.mp3"));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Agora com o arquivo criado, vamos compartilhar!!
    final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound.mp3"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Compartilhando no whatsapp"));


}
```

**Atenção!**

É necessário adicionar a seguinte permissão no `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Esta permite que o arquivo a ser compartilhado seja criado!

> A partir do Android 6.0 (nível de API 23), os usuários concedem
>   permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando
>   eles são instalados. Essa abordagem otimiza o processo de instalação
>   de aplicativos, pois o usuário não precisa conceder permissões ao
>   instalar ou atualizar o aplicativo

```
        // Verificamos se há permissão... (this = Activity)
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Devemos mostrar uma explicação?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Mostra uma extensão para o usuário * de forma assíncrona * - não bloqueie
                 // este tópico aguardando a resposta do usuário! Após o usuário
                 // vê a explicação, tente novamente solicitar a permissão.
            } else {

                // Nenhuma explicação necessária, podemos solicitar a permissão.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        CODE_REQUEST);

                // CODE_REQUEST é um int, que será comparado no onResult
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CODE_REQUEST: {
                // Se o pedido for cancelado, os arrays de resultados estão vazios.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // foi concedida permissão, Neste momento você tem a permissão consedida!
                } else {

//                    Não temos, permissão! 
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eu adicionei a permissão e o codigo direto sem modificar nada , pois vc ja tinha posto o o onclick e o nome da musica, quando apertei para compartilhar o app parou, nao sei o que devo fazer, pois nao modifiquei nada so copiei .

Comment: QUANDO NÃO SE SABE O QUE FAZER, OLHE O LOG CAT!  Lá vai dizer o que está acontecendo!

Comment: Verifique a permissão em tempo de execução https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=pt-br